# OSB WLS Initialisation issue

Tags: weblogic, mq, oracle-service-bus, osb

facing some strange behavior in OSB, i have configured WLS with MQ in client mode, i am doing some minor test to check the connection, i have created a proxy service to read the message from Q1 and a Business Service(BS) to route it to Q2. The issue is the proxy is able to read the message but the BS is throwing this:

> JMSPool BEA-169807 There was an error while making the initial connection to the JMS resource named ALSB_JMS_SessionPool_491704821 from within an EJB or a servlet. The server will attempt the connection again later. The error was javax.jms.JMSException: [JMSPool:169803]JNDI lookup of the JMS connection factory AKBConnFact failed: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory

Note: The classpath or the domain/lib folder contains the RefFSContextFactory class

Any ideas gang..? TIA

Comment: just to confirm, you've got fscontext.jar in the domain/lib ?

Comment: yesi have fscontext-0.jar in the domain/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this is a bug in OSB which needs to be reported.
As a workaround you need to individually set the jars in the weblogic classpath in your domain/server/bin folder. just go through the link below for more details:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2135523&start=0&tstart=0